# cannot convert 'a' (type 'int') to type 'double&

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I'm following some C++ tutorials, and frustratingly, the source material states this particular function call cannot be made, but doesn't at all explain why;

```
template<typename T>
void Swap(T &a, T &b){

    T temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

}
```

So now I create an explicit template function instantiation and pass in `a` and `b`;

```
int a = 5;
double b = 10.3;

Swap<double>(a, b);
```

Which then throws the following compiler error;

> cannot convert 'a' (type 'int') to type 'double&'

My only hunch is that this is because of the rule that states an rvalue can't be bound to a non-const reference, however, if `T &a` is just an alias, it's not an rvalue itself, is it? My implicit cast is creating a temporary, which it can't bind to `T &a`? Is that what's happening?

`temp` is an lvalue. It may only have function scope, but it does exist. So why wouldn't it allow the implicit cast to double, then assign the reference a to `temp`? The intention looks pretty clear. I don't quite understand references as parameters. If `a` is getting assigned to temp, which is an lvalue, then wouldn't this be allowed?

That's assuming I'm even on the right track here.

**Edit:**

A second example;

```
int a = 5;
double &d = a; // invalid initialization of reference of type 'double&' from expression of type 'int'
```

However;

```
int a = 5;
const double &d = a; //valid
```

Comment: A `double` reference needs a `double` variable to refer to.

Comment: What would you expect the value of `a` to be after the swap?

Comment: @Paul Roub - but wouldn't C++ implicitly cast an int to double to match the reference type? Or is this only in the case of variables?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lvalues or templates. Just read the error message.

Comment: @dari -I have. I'm asking *why* it isn't allowed.

Comment: @MartynShutt Values (of variables or literals) can be converted by casting, but here you need to pass a double variable to work with inside the function. Not just a double value. The function is allowed to do anything with it, eg. assigning double values or getting a double pointer of it

Comment: @deviantfan - so basically a reference *has* to point to a matching type?

Comment: @MartynShutt Basically yes, altough there are some other special things like const references and r-value references. But the reference you defined really needs a variable of it´s own type.

Comment: Put it this way. Would you write: `int a; double &b = a;`? If so, you're unclear on what references *are*.

Comment: @Paul Roub - I will update my question with another example, where this would be allowed.

Comment: @MartynShutt It works with `const` references because the `int` gets converted to a temporary `double`, and the temporary gets bound to the reference. This does not work with non-`const` references because it really doesn't make any sense. (The *temporary* would be the thing getting modified in `swap()`, not the original variable you tried to pass in!) So the language forbids this to happen.

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively, swapping `a` and `b` should work, because the compiler can convert between `int` and `double`. In practice, though, think about what the compiler has to do in order to do what you're asking.

You start with a template:

```
template<typename T>
void Swap(T &a, T &b){
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

To instantiate it for `double`, the compiler creates a function something like this:

```
void Swap(double& a, double& b) {
    double temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Those are *reference* parameters - they point to actual locations in memory, rather than being aliases or copies.  Under the hood, a reference behaves like a pointer, so you can think of your function similarly to this, if it helps:

```
void Swap(double* a, double *b);
```

In other words, `Swap` needs references (pointers) to two in-memory doubles - two 8-byte sections of memory (assuming a double takes 8 bytes).  As intelligent and intuitive humans, we know that `Swap`'s implementation doesn't really *need* two 8-byte sections of memory, but that's how it's declared, and so that's how the compiler enforces it.

To make a version of Swap that can handle mixed arguments, you'd have to do something like this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Swap(T1& a, T2& b) {
    T1 tmp(a);
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/LApyjz)

Comment: Needs 8 bytes? So if `a` was `uint64_t` it would work?

Comment: @Barry - I don't think it's a case of "would". It could, in theory, but any compiler strictly following the standard wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @Barry - No, obviously; barring `reinterpret_cast` or similar, it needs an 8 byte double, not 8 arbitrary bytes. I apologize if I wasn't clear or precise enough.

Comment: @JoshKelley But that's literally your answer: "Swap needs references... to two 8-byte sections of memory." You have no mention of types.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is effectively:

```
int a = 5;
double& dr = a;
```

The rules that govern reference initialization in the standard are in §8.5.3. First, some definitions:

> (4) Given types “*cv1* `T1`” and “*cv2* `T2`,” “*cv1* `T1`” is *reference-related* to “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is the same type as `T2`, or `T1` is a base class of `T2`. “*cv1* `T1`” is *reference-compatible* with “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is *reference-related* to `T2` and *cv1* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*.

Then, we have:

> (5) A reference to type “*cv1* `T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* `T2`” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`,”
>   - ..
>
> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case
>
> — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

The "then" case does not apply, since `int` is not reference-compatible with `double`. So we go to the other case, which states that the result should be an *rvalue* reference. That is, the reference shall be either:

```
const double& dcr = a; // lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type
double&& drr = a;      // rvalue reference
```

But that is not what your code is doing - hence the error. In fact, what you want to do is explicitly mentioned in the standard as a counter-example in the same bullet point:

```
int i = 2;
double& rd3 = i; // error: type mismatch and reference not const
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty clear. I really wanted to understand the rules governing the behavior, because although I can clearly see now why it isn't allowed, it wasn't intuitively clear to me. I've just downloaded a copy of the latest standard if I ever need specific clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is looking for a `Swap(int&, double&)`, because you supplied an `int` as the first parameter and a `double` as the second and it can't find one.

You could perform the following:

```
int a = 5;
double b = 10.3;
double c = a * 1.0;
Swap<double>(a, c);
```

Essentially, you declared a function that wants references to two `double`s.  When the compiler converts an `int` to a `double`, it creates a temporary.  You function doesn't want a temporary, because it may modify the value (which is what the reference means).

**Also, does it make sense to swap an integer with a floating point?**

Comment: the compiler isn't looking for `Swap(int&, double&)`, OP is calling `Swap<double>` explicitly.

Comment: The OP is technically calling `Swap<double>(int, double)`.